# php redirect and ical download issues

Tags: php

Our application have lots of old ical links and I am trying to redirect them to the new url. I can't do a .htaccess redirect because this new url is generated using php . There fore I am using php's header function to redirect users from redirect.php to test.php . But the problem is , if user access example.com/redirect.php .. ical file gets downloaded but the url in the browser remains example.com/redirect.php. It should have changed to example.com/test.php. I am using a 301 redirect.

I have tried javascript window.location.href function but the same results are coming in. I hope I have explained it properly. Thanks for the help.

First php file for example redirect.php have this code in place.

```
<?
header("Location: http://example.com/test.php");
?>
```

Second file test.php have this code to download an ical file. Code goes like this.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition: download; filename=calendar.ics");
echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
//echo "X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York\r\n";
echo "X-APPLE-CALENDAR-COLOR:#b91113\r\n";
echo "X-WR-CALNAME:$cal_name\r\n";
echo "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
echo "PRODID:-//Test//NONSGML Test//EN\r\n";
echo "METHOD:PUBLISH\r\n";
echo $data;?>
```

If I remove header code for Ical download, this redirect works. URL in the browser window changes to the new location.

Comment: What browser are you using? What behaviour do you see with other browsers? This is arguably a browser bug, but I don't even see how this is a problem. (Is there an RFC for redirects that specifies this?)

Comment: Hi Paul, I used Mozilla, IE , Google Chrome . In Mozilla , url in the browser tab remains example.com/redirect.php and ical file gets downloaded. Ical file download is inside test.php. In chrome and safari, even the redirect.php url doesn't get displayed in the window and the file gets downloaded. Since we have lots of old urls, I want users to see the new location when they load old urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redirect.php file should look like this:

```
 <?
 header("Location: http://example.com/test.php");
 exit;
 ?>
```

Try it out and let me know if it worked.

**Edit**

what browser are you testing on ? by any chance safari ? , i gues i figured out you're problem , the url stays the same becouse there is a download file at the requested uri , some browsers don't change the url when you're requesting a file for download ( that would mean the users sees a blank page ) , i know safari 4 does this tough i don't know any solution for it ( maybe change all you're links in you're site to the new uri but you still have a problem for google indexed uri's )

Comment: The exit's not necessary, since the entire file is one line.

Comment: Maybe it's not since this isn't the actual file but an example .

Comment: Hi Poelinca, Thanks a lot for your help :) . But it didn't work. I have included a test domain over here. But I tested this in a valid domain and the url redirect doesn't work after giving an exit. If I remove header code header("Content-Type: text/Calendar"); , redirect works.

Comment: header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition: download; filename=calendar.ics");

Comment: Thanks Poelinca, I am using Mozilla and also IE. If browser is one that is causing these issues.. then I guess I dont have much options now. I thought may be changing headers etc at the landing page will fix this redirect issue. Thanks for the help.